# Best algorithm to iterate a parent-child tree structure

Tags: java, tree

I've run into this time and time again, and I have a very simple solution but I am wondering what other algorithms might be cleaner and more maintainable. My specific use case involves dealing with a data pipeline where I will receive this structure many times and dispose of it after I am done. I will only ever need to iterate this structure once.

Say you have a tree structure with parent-child relationships; it is a one to many relationship with no boundaries.

```java
public class Node {
    private String name;

    private Boolean resource;

    private Node parent;

    private List<Node> children;

    // getters and setters...
}
```

Lets say I want to recursively search this structure starting from the root node BUT building an index of all nodes within the structure is more overhead than it is worth. I might write something like this:

```java
private static Node getNodeByName(Node node, String name) {
    if (node.getName().equals(name)) {
        return node;

    } else if (!node.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
        for (Node node : node.getChildren()) {
            Node childNode;

            if ((childNode = getNodeByName(node, name)) != null) {
                return childNode;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Lets change the requirement. Now we want to collect a `List` of `Node` that match a specific criteria.

```java
private static List<Node> getResourceNodes(Node node) {
    List<Node> matchedNodes = new ArrayList<>();
    SomeClass.getResourceNodes(node, matchedNodes);

    return matchedNodes;
}

private static void getResourceNodes(Node node, List<Node> matchedNodes) {
    if (node.isResource())) {
        matchedNodes.add(node);
    }

    if (!node.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
        for (Node node : node.getChildren()) {
            getResourceNodes(node, matchedNodes);
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote these here, directly. There might be a syntax error or two. I am wondering what other ways, perhaps something more maintainable, this could be written. It's how I have always approached linked nodes and now I'm curious to see if there is a better way.

Comment: Do you want depth-first or breadth-first?

Comment: @MichaelBianconi For the sake of keeping it inline with my examples, breadth-first.

Comment: @MichaelBianconi I withdraw my original comment. Understanding breadth-first doesn't look like it applies to my examples afterall. I suppose mine would be a depth-first approach?

Comment: I guess the criterion isn't always the same, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a cleaner and more maintainable algorithm, don't pass a list through the methods (building the list downwards). Instead, build the list upwards by returning it.

```java
private static List<Node> getResourceNodes(Node node) {

    List<Node> matchedNodes = new ArrayList<>();

    if (node.isResource()) matchedNodes.add(node);

    for (Node child : node.getChildren()) {
        matchedNodes.addAll(getResourceNodes(child);
    }

    return matchedNodes;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks good. For the sake of maintainability, I also threw in a `Predicate<Node>` parameter, which replaces the call to `isResources()`  with `criterion.test(node)`.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Michael's answer, I also added a `Predicate` to the method parameter. For the sake of maintainability, this should also be apart of the `Node` implementation.

```java
public class Node {
    //...

    private List<Node> filter(Predicate<Node> filter) {

        List<Node> matchedNodes = new ArrayList<>();

        if (filter.test(this)) matchedNodes.add(node);

        for (Node child : node.getChildren()) {
            matchedNodes.addAll(node.filter(filter));
        }

        return matchedNodes;
    }
}
```